# OpenWRT cannot see wifi settings in luci

Tags: wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I have upgraded to OpenWrt (just upgraded to Chaos Calmer 15.0 on a tp-link 1043nd ) but I cannot find the wifi settings in Luci (LuCI (git-15.248.30277-3836b45)  ). The wireless works fine, several computers are connected. But under 'Associated Stations' on status page it says 'No information available'.

How can I make the wireless settings visible in the web interface again?